# Python package resembling R's bpa (Basic Pattern Analysis)- package

Tags: python, r

Quite a simple question really: Is there a package in Python that resembles the bpa package found in R?

Link describing bpa's functionality:
[Basic Pattern Analysis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bpa/vignettes/introduction.html)

I have a column with mixed data, and I'd like to understand better in what format the data is. BPA provides in the following format (copied from the link I've attached):

```
messy$Date %>%
  get_pattern %>%  # extract patterns
  table %>%        # tabulate frequencies
  as.data.frame    # display as a data frame

##                    . Freq
## 1         99/99/9999  262
## 2         9999-99-99  259
## 3          99Aaa9999  241
## 4  Aaaaaaaaaw99w9999   19
## 5   Aaaaaaaaw99w9999   56
## 6    Aaaaaaaw99w9999   45
## 7     Aaaaaaw99w9999   24
## 8      Aaaaaw99w9999   36
## 9       Aaaaw99w9999   42
## 10       Aaaw99w9999   16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a function that resembles the BPA `get_pattern` function using python:

```py
import re

def get_pattern(x, show_ws = True, ws_char = '<>'):
    
    if pd.isnull(x):
        x = np.nan
    else:
        if not isinstance(x, str):
            x = str(x)      

            x = re.sub("[a-z]", "a", x)
            x = re.sub("[A-Z]", "A", x)
            x = re.sub("[0-9]", "9", x)

        if isinstance(x, str):

            x = re.sub("[a-z]", "a", x)
            x = re.sub("[A-Z]", "A", x)
            x = re.sub("[0-9]", "9", x)

    
        if show_ws == True: 
            x = re.sub("\\s", ws_char, x)
  
    return(x)
```